# Force generating thumbnails on DiskStation DSM

Tags: synology, thumbnails

I would like my Synology DiskStation to generate thumbnails of pictures present on specific folders.

**DSM version:** DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 9

I set up Media Indexing that way:

`Control Panel > Indexing service > Media Indexing`, then click on `Indexed Folder`, and add my folders with Photo checkbox ticked. My 'thumbnail quality' is set on Normal Quality.

I am adding pictures to the server via SFTP or such non-software related medium, and no thumbnails appear to be generated (only one image has been added, and no thumb after 24h). The only way it generates the thumbnails is when I manually launch Photo Station and browse to those folders which is NOT the way I want (plus, that way seem to have the following flaws: it doesn't manage all the jpgs I have, even in the same folder (why??) + it uses a compression algorithm which doesn't compress much (a 1:4 thumbs have half the size of my original (thumbmail quality setting: Normal Quality)).

I read everywhere people wanting their Diskstation NOT to auto-generate thumbnails, but I want it TO. Apparently, CPU-use is the main reason for people to get rid of it, so if there's a light way to do it, it'll come first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you might want to try using SSH to connect to your DiskStation. Then, you can use the 'synoindex' command. For more information on that command, try 'synoindex --help' or have a look at the following page which was very helpful for me: https://www.my-it-brain.de/wordpress/synology-nas-einzelnen-ordner-neu-indizieren/